# How to play music when receive local notification on background

Tags: ios, objective-c, uilocalnotification, background-music

I'm making an alarm function for my app and local notification is one of method I have searched. But when receive local notification it enable only 30s for it sound while I want my alarm play sound on 15 minute.

I can make 1 alarm sound on 15 minute with 30 notifications but my app need create a lot of alarm while iOS app allow only  64 or 128 local notifications. So I would like to run music on background when receive the notification, but how to do this?

Can anybody help me with this?
Many thanks.

Answer (score -1):

If you want your app to play a 15 minute sound then you are going to need to set it up with the background mode flags in info.plist that declare it as a background sound playing app. You'll then need to ask for background time and quit background mode once your sound is complete.

Comment: Can you give me some details, all I need is do something after receive local notification when app on background or may be app on suspended state. How to ask for background time? (for example: I create a local notification and it will fire after 2 hour when app on background, at this time I want play an audio)

Comment: The big issue is that you can support background audio, but local notifications don't allow you to wake the app up to run the code in the background. I am trying to do this same thing. YOU CAN wake your app up with a remote silent notification but these are not very reliable and you need REMOTE to do it.